# Select multiple condition in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
$querySelectItems = "SELECT * FROM auction_items WHERE auction_items.Itm_status = 'Pending' OR auction_items.Itm_status = 'Fail' AND Item_userid = :uid";

$stmtSelectItems = $conn->prepare($querySelectItems);   
$stmtSelectItems->bindParam(':uid',$_SESSION['userid']);                 
$stmtSelectItems->execute();
```

Above code cant work , i want to select if the **itm_status = pending or itm_status = fail** will list out the detals, but i try write above code cannot work~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$querySelectItems = "SELECT * FROM auction_items WHERE (auction_items.Itm_status = 'Pending' OR auction_items.Itm_status = 'Fail') AND Item_userid = :uid";
```

Comment: added brackets on the conditions (y)

Comment: @Poria, I am very sorry, but cannot understand the instruction.

Comment: I was just stating what changes you made in the query above.. thanks